# Mysql remote access using TCP / IP not TCP / IP via SSH

Tags: mysql, ssh, mysql-workbench

I am connected to the internal network via VPN. On a remote server I have an ubuntu system that I connect to via SSH. I have the MySql database installed on my Ubuntu system. Currently, I can connect to the specified database remotely via TCP / IP via SSH using MySQL Workbench. The problem is that I need to be connected via TCP / IP. What do I have to change in the settings to establish a connection using TCP/IP?

Comment: Check in /etc/my.cnf that the bind address is on a "proper" ip address, rather than just the loopback.

Comment: I set 0.0.0.0 and address ip of my server without success.

Comment: netstat -anp | grep :3306? check firewall? telnet <host> 3306? tcptraceroute <host> 3306?

Comment: I use Windows 10 as host.

Comment: Doesn't netstat or similar exist on Windows? I'm sure telnet can be installed, and Windows does have a firewall.

Comment: Thanks to the given commands, I came to the conclusion that the port is disabled on the remote server, i.e. in the virtual machine itself it is activated but blocked by the network administrator. I will contact the administrator. Then we'll see

Comment: After a few tries, the situation is as follows:
From the virtual machines where I have the server installed, calling telnet comments ` `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 3306` gives `Escape character is '^]'.
[
|sff%caching_sha2_passwordPuTTY2#08S01` . From Windows 10 is `Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306: Connect failed`